# PHP oAuth always returns code 400

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, twitter-oauth, tumblr

I am connecting to Tumblr (it's the same process as twitter almost identical).
I get all the way through to the verify page, verify the app, then get returned to the previos page, all of the correct stuff is on the querystring but i get a 400 error a bit on the API docs says that this means "invalid input data".

Here's my code:

```
        require("tumblr/tumblroauth/tumblroauth.php");
        // Enter your Consumer / Secret Key:
        $consumer   = $conf['Tumblr']['consumer'];
        $secret     = $conf['Tumblr']['secret'];
        /* Start session and load lib */
        if(!isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']))
        {
            // Start the Session
            session_start();
            $connection = new TumblrOAuth($conf['Tumblr']['consumer'], $conf['Tumblr']['secret']);
                    // this url is correct
            $url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
            $temporary_credentials = $connection->getRequestToken($url);
            $redirect_url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($temporary_credentials, FALSE);

            echo "going to".$redirect_url; // looks good
                    //have to use this as headers have started
            echo '<script>window.location.href="'.$redirect_url.'";</script>';
        }

        /* If the oauth_token is old redirect to the connect page. */
        if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token']) {
          $_SESSION['oauth_status'] = 'oldtoken';
          session_destroy();
        }
        if(isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']))
        {/* Create TumblroAuth object with app key/secret and token key/secret from default phase */
            $connection = new TumblrOAuth($consumer, $secret, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

            /* Request access tokens from tumblr */
            $access_token = $connection->getAccessToken($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

            /* Save the access tokens. Normally these would be saved in a database for future use. */
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

            /* Remove no longer needed request tokens */
            unset($_SESSION['oauth_token']);
            unset($_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);

            /* If HTTP response is 200 continue otherwise send to connect page to retry */
            if (200 == $connection->http_code) {
              /* The user has been verified and the access tokens can be saved for future use */
              $_SESSION['status'] = 'verified';
              echo 'connection made heres the code:<br/>'.$connection->http_code;
            } else {
              /* Save HTTP status for error dialog on connnect page.*/


                     // THIS IS ALWAYS BEING OUTPUT AT THE END
             echo "oh no something is wrong code:<br/>".$connection->http_code;
            }
        }
```

Please can someone have a look I feel like I have tried everything on the planet to get this to work..
ps using : https://github.com/jacobbudin/tumblroauth

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
    $redirect_url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($temporary_credentials, FALSE);
```

Try

```
    $redirect_url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($temporary_credentials);
```

and let us know if you're still having trouble